# Error in tapply() output return a vector of factors

Tags: r, tapply

When reading a data frame into R with read.csv() and using tapply() to compute treatment means, the result is a vector of factors.

```
cfpr<-read.csv("E:/temp/vars.csv",sep=";")
 cfpr
    ano mes usd_brl      x        y
1  2014   5   2.221 181.83 403.8444
2  2014   6   2.236 172.37 385.4193
3  2014   7   2.225 169.27 376.6257
4  2014   8   2.268 175.89 398.9185
5  2015   5   3.064 144.79 443.6366
6  2015   6   3.111 151.12 470.1343
7  2015   7   3.224 135.75 437.6580
8  2015   8   3.515 135.27 475.4740
9  2016   5   3.549 135.26 480.0377
10 2016   6   3.418 145.22 496.3620
11 2016   7   3.278 155.80 510.7124
12 2016   8   3.208 156.61 502.4049
 class(cfpr$ano)
[1] "integer"
 class(cfpr$y)
[1] "numeric"
 tapply(cfpr$y,cfpr$ano,fun=mean)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

If the data frame columns are renamed tapply() works again:

```
> cfpr<-read.csv("E:/temp/vars.csv",sep=";")
> cfpr
    ano mes usd_brl      x        y
1  2014   5   2.221 181.83 403.8444
2  2014   6   2.236 172.37 385.4193
3  2014   7   2.225 169.27 376.6257
4  2014   8   2.268 175.89 398.9185
5  2015   5   3.064 144.79 443.6366
6  2015   6   3.111 151.12 470.1343
7  2015   7   3.224 135.75 437.6580
8  2015   8   3.515 135.27 475.4740
9  2016   5   3.549 135.26 480.0377
10 2016   6   3.418 145.22 496.3620
11 2016   7   3.278 155.80 510.7124
12 2016   8   3.208 156.61 502.4049
> colnames(cfpr)[4:5]<-c("X","Y")
> class(cfpr$ano)
[1] "integer"
> class(cfpr$Y)
[1] "numeric"
> tapply(cfpr$Y,cfpr$ano,mean)
    2014     2015     2016 
391.2020 456.7257 497.3792
```

How can I avoid this error and renaming the data every time?

Link to the data as I'm using it: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PhiuQIptVNylPFohDpl5AIDr94xxlf5p

Additional info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2
```

Comment: The parameter in `tapply()` to give the function is `FUN=`. So you have to do `tapply(cfpr$y,cfpr$ano, FUN=mean)` Compare: `tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, FUN=mean)` vs. `tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, fun=mean)`

Comment: I voted to close because of *typo*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem is not with the column names but with the argument, you're passing in function tapply.

Below snippet explains your doubt.

```
> cfpr = read.csv("vars.csv",sep = ';')
> head(cfpr)
   ano mes usd_brl      x        y
1 2014   5   2.221 181.83 403.8444
2 2014   6   2.236 172.37 385.4193
3 2014   7   2.225 169.27 376.6257
4 2014   8   2.268 175.89 398.9185
5 2015   5   3.064 144.79 443.6366
6 2015   6   3.111 151.12 470.1343
> class(cfpr$ano)
[1] "integer"
> class(cfpr$y)
[1] "numeric"
> ## Method 1
> tapply(cfpr$y, cfpr$ano, mean)
    2014     2015     2016 
391.2020 456.7257 497.3792 
> ## Method 2
> tapply(cfpr$y, cfpr$ano, FUN = function(x){mean(x)})
    2014     2015     2016 
391.2020 456.7257 497.3792
```

Note that if you need to pass the function to apply, you need to give argument `FUN`. For more references check tapply's documentation by typing `?tapply`.

Hope this clears your doubt.